# WPF Custom WindowChrome exception when invoke Close() in Loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window-chrome

#### Scenario:

- WPF window (`CustomWindow`) with custom template/[WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx).
- **Problem:** Attempt to close the window in the `Loaded` event throws `NullReferenceException`.
- Workaround:

  1. If I comment out the `WindowChrome` setter, then it works.

     - But lose custom chrome
  2. If I delay for some arbitrary duration, before closing the window, then it works.

     - Feels wrong using delays

#### Question:

Only the delay workaround allows me to 1) retain my custom window chrome and 2) not throw an exception.

But the delay solution feels like a hack.

***Is there a better way to do this?***

---

#### CustomWindow xaml

```
<Style TargetType="v:CustomWindow">
    <!-- Workaround 1: Works when commented out -->
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomWindow}">
                <DockPanel Background="White">
                    <!-- Caption bar -->
                    <Grid Background="Cyan" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <!-- Title -->
                            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />

                            <!-- Close button -->
                            <Button Width="30" Command="SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                    Content="Close" />


                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Window content -->
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### Usage

```
var dialog = new CustomWindow();
dialog.Loaded += async delegate
{
    // On loaded, do something, then close immediately

    // await Task.Delay(10); // <-- Workaround 2: Uncomment this, and it seems to work
    dialog.Close();
};
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

#### The stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._ExtendGlassFrame()
at System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._UpdateFrameState(Boolean force)
at System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._ApplyNewCustomChrome()
at System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._WindowSourceInitialized(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
at System.Windows.Window.Show()
at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
```

Environment:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2017
- .NET 4.6.1

## Solution

Changing the code to the following works:

```
var dialog = new CustomWindow();
dialog.Loaded += delegate
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
        delegate
        {
            // On loaded, do something, then close immediately
            dialog.Close();
        })
    );
};
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I have not tried it, but you could use the ContentRendered event to close the window. This event can fire multiple times, so you could mark the first execution with a boolean flag. I can add this as answer with an example if it works (too difficult on my mobile)

Comment: try `ContentRendered` event instead of `Loaded`, it raises after Loaded

Comment: @Scoregraphic and @tetralobita thanks for replying. Using `ContentRendered`, I did not get any errors. However, will be going with @grek40's solution.

Comment: Confirm same problem. Custom Window Chrome in the wpf window. If Close() is called on Loaded handler, ShowDialog() in the owner window throws null reference exption. Playn with Dispatched schdulin g of Close() never helped me. Got away with closing it like this:

`ContentRendered += (o, e) => Close(); return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the Dispatcher to delay your closing until all typical work is completed:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(ShutMeDown), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

I'm not completely sure whether `DispatcherPriority.Background` is the right one, but the basic idea is that your window chrome will initialize itself with some work priority and your shutdown should take place with a lower priority so it will be postponed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Tried it with every combination of `DispatcherPriority`, and all of them seemed to work (except `Invalid` and `Inactive`). I did consider using the Dispatcher initially, but made the mistake of using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke`.